# Is the logistic function continuous

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

By using the Epsilon Delta Definition I have to prove that $$f(x)=\frac{e^x}{1+e^x}$$

is continuous on R s.t

$|\Delta f| <\epsilon$ and $|\Delta x| < \delta$

I'm not really sure what to do

Comment: What theorems about continuity do you have at your disposal?. Do you know that $e^x$ is continuous?  Do you know that if $f$ and $g$ are continuous that $f + g$ is continuous and $f/g$ is continuous if $g(x) \ne 0$ for any x?  $e^x > 0$ so $e^x + 1 > 1 > 0$ for all real $x$.

Comment: ... if you know those things, then the continuity follows.  If you don't know those things, we'll have to prove them... which we can do.  So, at this stage of your course, what can we assume you know?

Comment: I know $e^x$ is continuous and $f+g$ $f$/$g$ is continuous then continuity follows. But in my course we have not proven $e^x$ is continuous. I must therefore use the Epsilon Delta Definition to prove $f(x)$ is continuous.

Comment: Would it be acceptable to prove $e^x$ is continuous and then conclude $f(x)$ is continuous?  Proving $e^x$ via delta epsilon is straightforward and I can help you with that.  Proving $f(x)$ directly is ... kind of a pain but not impossible.

Comment: I would like to prove both $e^x$ is continuous and $f(x)$ is continuous . If it's okay. I really appreciate your help and time.

Answer (score 1):

Okay.  To prove $e^x$ is continuous at a fixed point $w \in \mathbb R$.

If we assume $\epsilon > 0$ we have to find a $\delta_{\epsilon} > 0$ such that:

If $|x - w| < \delta$ then it must follow that $|e^x - e^w| < \epsilon$.  So we must figure out what is required for the second condition to always be true.

So if $|e^x - e^w| = |e^w(e^{x-w} - 1)| = e^w*|1 - e^{x-y}|$.

So $|e^x - e^w| < \epsilon \iff |1- e^{x-w}| = |1 - e^x/e^w| < e^{-w}*\epsilon$.

This will be true if $e^x/e^w = e^{x-w} < \min(|e^{-w}*\epsilon - 1|,|e^{-w}*\epsilon + 1| )$.

This will be true if $|x - w| < \min(\ln(|e^{-w}*\epsilon -1|), \ln(|e^{-w}*\epsilon + 1|)$

So.. for any $\epsilon > 0$ we can choose $\delta = \min(\ln(|e^{-w}*\epsilon -1|), \ln(|e^{-w}*\epsilon + 1|)$.  Then it follows that $|e^x - e^w| < \epsilon$

So $e^x$ is continuous at $w$.  We can do this for all $r \in \mathbb R$ so $e^x$ is continuous on all reals.

Then we can conclude $e^x + 1$ and $e^x/(1 + e^x)$ are continuous on all reals.